# Avoid line break in R Markdown output

Tags: r, formatting, r-markdown

I'm wondering how I can get all of the elements from my output on one single line, as the space for it is clearly there.

[image: Screenshot from R Markdown]

Preamble of the file:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
````

Comment: Welcome to SO. Is this homework? Maybe have a look at this link: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions.

Comment: Try to increase the console width, `options(width=100)` just after the `knitr::` line.

Comment: @Peter Rather looks like OP is _creating_ homework ;)

Comment: Thanks, jay. Well, it’s not "homework", just some practice data. And my inquiry is clearly regarding something else rather than the question itself.